# How can I overlap widgets on a window?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, game-development

I am doing an assignment in which I have to program a game that emulates a very basic version of a platform game. In order to make the game screen I have to make a layout in like a board shape in which you can add characters and elements (such as walls, rocks, etc).

I am trying to do this by setting every element in the game screen (background included) as a widget. The thing is that I really don't know how can I overlap widgets. I first tried with making a QVBoxLayout with multiple QHBoxLayout that represent a line on the board and every widget in the QHBoxLayout makes up for a column on the board. I tried overlaping this background layout to a test layout of the characters made in a similar way in which I made the background layout. I tried the overlap using two QWidgets as containers for each layout and adding these as widgets of a QStackedLayout but it doesn't really works because the first layout added to the QStackedLayout shows up covering completely the background layout.

This is my code if it helps to clear out what I tried to explain before.
If you know why this doesn't work to what I intend to do please feel free to explain why or if you can share resources for me to learn how can I overlap widgets (in this context) since in school they only thaught us how to create windows, main windows, buttons, typing boxes, labels and then asked to do a whole functional game :).

Any kind of advice will be much appreciated.

```
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_gui()
    def init_gui(self):
        self.setGeometry(450, 300, 730, 650)
        container1 = QWidget()
        container2= QWidget()

        layout1 = QVBoxLayout(container1)
        layout2 = QVBoxLayout(container2)

        for i in range(14):
            hbox = QHBoxLayout()
            for j in range(9):
                label = QLabel("")
                pix = QPixmap(r"sprites\Personajes\luigi_front")
                label.setPixmap(pix)
                label.setScaledContents(True)
                hbox.addWidget(label)
            layout1.addLayout(hbox)
            layout1.setSpacing(0)


        for i in range(14):
            hbox = QHBoxLayout()
            for j in range(9):
                label = QLabel("")
                pix = QPixmap(r"sprites\Elementos\backg")
                label.setPixmap(pix)
                label.setScaledContents(True)
                hbox.addWidget(label)
            layout2.addLayout(hbox)
            layout2.setSpacing(0)
    

        stack = QStackedLayout()
        stack.addWidget(container1)
        stack.addWidget(container2)

        self.setLayout(stack)

        self.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    form = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

These are the images I'm using :
[backg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoPr3.png)
[luigi_front](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8s0T.png)

The code above is a test window that I made to see if I could overlap two layouts in order to make the game screen for the program I am trying to do. I tried using QStackedWindow to see if I could overlap the "front" layout (layout1) and the background layout (layout2). I expected to see a window with a board (9x14) and the background image (back) and the character image (luigi_front) in front of each background square. This is not the case since the outcome of the program is simply a board with only characters images as shown below:

[program outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUwyF.png)

Note: I can't use QTDesigner for this lol.

Comment: PyQt5 is a framework designed to develop GUI applications (such as word, excel, etc...). You could create what you want using QtOpenGL, but that's another step for such a simple assignment. If you're not bound to use PyQt5, my recomendation is to use a game-development framework, such as Unity (javascript or C#), or even Pygame (Python). Its far simpler to use them, than finding a way to do it inside Qt5's engine.

Comment: You cannot (nor should try to) do it with layouts, that's not their purpose. Actually, this can be done with Qt, and without using OpenGL. While technically possible to do that with QWidgets (by implementing custom painting or child widgets that have explicitly set geometries), I wouldn't suggest it, as the complexity of geometry relations and shape management would make things more difficult than they should. Instead, use the [Graphics View framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html), which is perfectly capable of allowing all this.